# Diff an array of objects so that it matches another without recreating any valid objects

Tags: javascript, array-algorithms

Let's say I have 2 arrays each of which holds a few different objects

```
class Object1 {}
class Object2 {}
class Object3 {}
class Object4 {}
class Object5 {}
class Object6 {}

const arrayA = [
  new Object1(), 
  new Object2(), 
  new Object3()
]
const arrayB = [
  new Object4(), 
  new Object1(), 
  new Object2(), 
  new Object6()
]
```

I need to mutate arrayB so that it holds instances of the same classes as arrayA in the same order.

But I need to reuse any instances in arrayB of classes that are also present in arrayA.

The desired output here would be:

```
  arrayB = [
    instanceOfObject1AlreadyInArrayB,
    instanceOfObject2AlreadyInArrayB,
    new Object3()
  ]
```

How would you solve this with the best possible big O notation?

Are there any comparable algorithm names I can research?

Comment: can you mod the constructors to memoize the last created instance and return it instead of _this_? that keeps you from creating un-needed dupes in the first place, so reconciliation would be dirt cheap.

Comment: No I cannot mod the constructor. I don't own these objects. They come from a library that does functional style === checks on instances. Re-using instances prevents a lot of work from being re-done which is why I'd like to avoid it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach here is to copy `arrayB` into a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) from each element's `constructor` to its value.  Then we can iterate over `arrayA`'s elements and for each one, if its `constructor` is a key in the `Map` we use the existing value, otherwise we construct a new instance.

The time complexity of this is essentially just *O(a+b)* where *a* is the length of `arrayA` and *b* is the length of `arrayB`, assuming that operations on a `Map` are constant-time *O(1)*.  Technically the spec only requires that it be sublinear, so then all we can say for sure is that the time complexity of the whole process is strictly less than *O((a+b)<sup>2</sup>)*, so at the least it scales better than iterating `arrayB` for each element of `arrayA` (e.g., `arrayA.map(a => arrayB.find(⋯)`) , which would be *O(a×b)*.

And because apparently you want `arrayB` to be *mutated*, we can clear `arrayB` after copying its contents to the `Map`, and then just push the elements onto it.  This is *O(a)* and thus doesn't affect the overall time complexity.

Here is an example:

```js
// not necessary, just adding a common constructor so that we can
// see exactly when new instances are being constructed
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    console.log("constructed " + this.constructor.name)
  }
}
class Object1 extends Parent { }
class Object2 extends Parent { }
class Object3 extends Parent { }
class Object4 extends Parent { }
class Object5 extends Parent { }
class Object6 extends Parent { }

console.log("making arrayA")
const arrayA = [
  new Object1(),
  new Object2(),
  new Object3()
]
console.log("making arrayB")
const arrayB = [
  new Object4(),
  new Object1(),
  new Object2(),
  new Object6()
]

const map = new Map();
arrayB.forEach(v => map.set(v.constructor, v));
arrayB.length = 0;
console.log("recreating arrayB contents")
arrayA.forEach(v => arrayB.push(map.get(v.constructor) ?? new v.constructor()));

console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayB.map(x => x.constructor.name)))
```

If you run that snippet you'll see that `arrayB` ends up with instances of `Object1`, `Object2`, and `Object3` in that order, but only the `Object3` constructor gets invoked; the `Object1` and `Object2` instances from `arrayB` are re-used.

Answer (score 0):

Identify the classes present in `arrayA` that are not in `arrayB`. Using the `filter()` on `arrayA`, check if each class is included in `arrayB`, if not, add it to a new array and create new instances of these classes and add them to `arrayB`. Add variable `missingClasses`, this contains the classes that are in `arrayA` but not in `arrayB`, and use it to create the new instances. Then, make sure that the objects in `arrayB` are in the same order as in `arrayA`.

```
const classesInA = arrayA.map(obj => obj.constructor);
const classesInB = arrayB.map(obj => obj.constructor);
const missingClasses = classesInA.filter(cls => !classesInB.includes(cls));

const newInstances = missingClasses.map(cls => new cls());

// Remove objects from arrayB that are not in arrayA
arrayB = arrayB.filter(obj => classesInA.includes(obj.constructor));

const sortedArrayB = arrayB.concat(newInstances).sort((a, b) => {
 return classesInA.indexOf(a.constructor) - classesInA.indexOf(b.constructor);
});
```

Comment: So this is almost there. But it doesn't remove the objects from B that are not in A. I believe the output of this in my example would erroneously include an instance of Object4 and Object6 in the output

Comment: I edit the code to creates a new array that includes only the objects in ```arrayB``` that are also in ```arrayA``` and removes the objects from ```arrayB``` that are not in ```arrayA```.